# Want to delete old entries from SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I want to delete all entries from my database that are older than 2 or 3 months. The thing is all of my tables do not contain date column. Is there any way to delete old data from all the tables in my database that has a date column?

Comment: How do *you* tell that a row is older than 2 or 3 (which do you actually want) months old? If you can't tell, how do you suppose SQL Server can..?

Comment: So, how the heck are you even going to know which entries are old? it is not like they collect dust - and you say you have no marker. ID field? Anything?

Comment: Short answer - no. And just because a row is "old" doesn't mean it is not referenced by "new" rows or is otherwise required for your system to work.

Answer (score 0):

Add a nullable date column with default of GetDate(). Wait two months and delete everything that has a null in that column or date older than two months